CAPL SCRIPT. How to read second byte data
I am trying to write a CAPL script to compare diagnostic DID response to panel text value.
How can I access second byte of a diagresponse.
For ex : diagGetComplexParameter(Resp_F121,"Logical_Block_0_Part_Number", 0, "Logical_Block_0_Part_Number");
Resp_F121 is the DID response for F121. But I want to read the second byte value of the DID, which I am unable to, I can read the first byte by the above function.
The response of the DID is as below:

I am trying to extract the highlighted data.

I suggest you need to use a function form with "output" parameter
double myerror = 0, output[1] = {0};
char parameterName[128] = "Logical_Block_0_Part_Number", subName[128] = "Logical_Block_0_Part_Number";
dword i;
  
myerror = 0;

for(i=0; i < DiagGetIterationCount(this, parameterName); i++){  
    myerror = diagGetComplexParameter(Resp_F121, parameterName, i, subName, output);
    write("iteration %d = %x", i, output[0]);
} 

as in help:
output Output field. If given, output contains the value of the parameter after return of this method.
is it possible to show the SubParameter Name of PartNumber-Parameter in Symbol Selection?
Like: 
Or just try support@vector.com
